# Reading from a (log) file, extracting values and performing operations on them in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, extract, filereader

Suppose there is a log file called logfile.log. It could also be in txt or csv formats. It contents are as shown below (bandwidth is in KB):

```
CustomerID: 1001  bandwidth: 5000  CarrierType: A  Region: US
CustomerID: 2001  bandwidth: 4000  CarrierType: B  Region: UK
CustomerID: 1001  bandwidth: 2000  CarrierType: A  Region: US
CustomerID: 3001  bandwidth: 1000  CarrierType: C  Region: JPN
CustomerID: 2001  bandwidth: 500   CarrierType: B  Region: UK
```

I would like to do the following:

1. Find total bandwidth associated with each customer id
2. Cost of Each Carrier Type is- carriertype A: $0.40 per KB, carriertype B: $0.60 per KB, carriertype C: 0.80 per KB
   List the customer ids with the greatest total amount in descending order
3. For Each region find the total bandwidth consumed

I would like to know if I could use a string-tokenizer to split and store various values into variables or if I should use Regex?

Would you suggest storing values into a Hashmap, an Array or a List?

I would also like to know how I could find total values for the conditions mentioned in my question.

Thank You.

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if I could use a string-tokenizer to split and store various values into variables or if I should use Regex?

Either approach would work.  I suggest you try the approach that seems simplest.

> Would you suggest storing values into a Hashmap, an Array or a List?

It sounds like you need (at least) a `HashMap` that maps customer ids to objects that represent the customer's usage.

> I would also like to know how I could find total values for the conditions mentioned in my question.

Add them up :-)

Either keep running totals as you read the log file, or make one or more passes over the in-memory data structure.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if I could use a string-tokenizer to split and
>   store various values into variables or if I should use Regex?

I guess - Regex are efficient.

> Would you suggest storing values into a Hashmap, an Array or a List?

HashMaps of customer-ids, carrierType, regions. It will be easy [O(1)] to make any updates.

> I would also like to know how I could find total values for the
>   conditions mentioned in my question.

It is always good to keep running totals as and when u read log files. It will scale well on growing files...